# How to distinguish what cancelled Game Services sign in?

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

Using [GameHelper](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java) in my game, I paid attention that onActivityResult() if I get Activity.RESULT_CANCELED - the assumption is that user cancelled the sign in. In the other hand, according to Android documentation:

> If a child activity fails for any reason (such as crashing), the parent activity will receive a result with the code RESULT_CANCELED.

For me, it seems that in some old devices, I get RESULT_CANCELED as a result of some crash on low connectivity, and it makes me some issues.

The question is - can be RESULT_CANCELED as a result of crash, and if it can, how can i differ between user cancelled and crash?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use requestCode parameter of onActivityResult method :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(requestCode == GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN_REQ) {
      // TODO : implement your logic
   }
}
```

You need to learn value of requestCode by trying out sign in cancel scenarios or looking into GameHelper.java source code. After that you can set this value to a static final GOOGLE_PLUS_LOGIN_REQ variable and use as stated above.